# Auto expire post

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a adpost website and I want to add a feature where an ad changes status from 'active' to 'inactive' after 30 days. So what should be the query for that or JavaScript can do the job?

Also please tell me how to do it.

Comment: You need to set a crone job on your server that will run the specific code to change the post status.

Comment: Is you objective to simply not return expired ads with `SELECT` queries or do you want to delete them? A SQL solution in either case, one would typically use a WHERE clause to identify ads with an expiration date older than 30 days from the current date.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com) is the tool you are looking for.

Comment: depending on the SQL Server version you're using, a scheduled "ad maintenance" job would be an option, too.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, which are you *actually* using? I've removed the conflicting tags for you. Please update them appropriately.

Comment: @DanGuzman I need to update on the database as I have given people option to activate it again if they want.

Comment: Why do need to update the database for expiration? Specify the `WHERE` clause I suggested so that only non-expired ads are returned. To reactivate an expired ad, change the expiration date.

Comment: @Larnu I use MySQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30 days is a long time.  There are essentially two methods.

The first is to use a regularly scheduled job that changes the status on ads.  Essentially, something like this:

```
update ads
    set status = 'inactive'
    where create_date < current_timestamp - interval '30 day';
```

(The exact syntax and table/column references depend on your system.)

A second method is to create a view:

```
create view v_ads as
    select a.*
    from ads a
    where create_date > current_timestamp - interval '30 day';
```

This only fetches the ads within the last 30 days.  You never have to update the database, and you can adjust the time interval whenever you like.